# How does a variable declared in switch statement out of case work?

Tags: c, variables, switch-statement

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a = 1;

    switch(a) {
        int t= 4;
    case 1:
        printf("%d", t);
        break;
    default: //Does not mean anything just for clarity
        break;
    }
}
```

Result in C11 gcc:
1

Question: Why is this working? Isn't the compiler supposed to give an error?
if a is 1, shouldn't it just jump to case 1? Why is it printing 1?

Comment: What exact compile options did you use ? And did you use -Wall to get all the warnings ?

Comment: *Why is this working?* Why do you think it is working? You think you have initialized `t` with `4` and when you print `t` you get `1`.Is it really working?

Comment: I think that the people who voted to dupe the question did a rather lazy reading.

Comment: compiling the posted code causes the compiler to output: "10:9: warning: 't'' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]"  Which is ALL you need to know.  The code does not work as your hoping.

Comment: It builds because in C, variables can be used wherever in their declaring scope (curly braces) after they've been declared. `int t` within the `switch` is a directive to the compiler to reserve space for a variable, and that space exists regardless of whether the statement is executed or not. However, the variable only has a value if the statement is executed.

Comment: Reading from an uninitialized variable is not an error in C, however the value is undetermined. This means that it could be anything, and that the reason you get any specific value is not necessarily obvious or easy to explain. In general, the uninitialized value of a variable is just the value of whatever sat in the location of that variable before.

Comment: I agree with zneak : This question is not a duplicate of the other one but it HAS answers in the other question.

Comment: **Utterly wrong duplicate**, shame on you. The incorrect duplicate was even tagged with [tag:c] even though it was of **C++ only**.

Comment: here's the C one

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You'll get warnings. Improve your code to get none.

Comment: It seems this has been asked 1223421123 times already. Next time enter your **title into Google search first**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you missed a couple.

Answer (score 2):

t has been declared in the current scope, so there is no reason to have an error.
Now, but you never go through its initialisation which is made before any label, so it can have any value. What puzzles me, is if there any reason why it coincidentally equals 1.

Comment: undefined behavior means anything can happen